Is typing.assert_never() removed by command line option -O, similar to assert statement?
In Python, assert statement produces no code if command line optimization options -O or -OO are passed. Does it happen for typing.assert_never()? Is it safe to declare runtime assertions that will not be optimized out?
Consider the case
from typing import assert_never

def func(item: int | str):
    match item:
        case int():
            ...
        case str():
            ...
        case _:
            assert_never(item)

Is it guaranteed that the default branch will work even in optimized mode?

assert_never can theoretically be overridden, unlike an assert statement, and no reasonable Python implementation will spend the effort to rule out any such code that would allow the call to be optimized away.

I feel like my answer could use a better explanation, so I updated it. TL;DR: You can define and use your own assert_never().

No. assert_never() is only a normal function consisting of a raise statement, at least in CPython. It is not removed at runtime, as with other typing features.

It should be emphasized that assert_never() has nothing special: It just takes in an argument of type Never and never returns anything (i.e., it raises):
def assert_never(arg: Never) -> Never:
    raise AssertionError("Expected code to be unreachable")

Its inclusion in the stdlib was simply due to the expectation that it would be commonly used. To quote the typing guides:

Because the assert_never() helper function is frequently useful, it is provided by the standard library as typing.assert_never starting in Python 3.11, and is also present in typing_extensions starting at version 4.1.
— § assert_never() and Exhaustiveness Checking | Python typing guides

The same section also says:

However, it is also possible to define a similar function in your own code, for example if you want to customize the runtime error message.


That's how it's currently implemented in CPython, but is it required to not be implemented by assert False?

The name could refer to any callable, and it's not worth the effort to simulate the code to ensure that assert_never has the same semantics as assert False.
